# Constructing sentence with passive verb

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I am learning how to construct a japanese phrase with passive verb.

From "Mira-san wa watashi o pa-ti- ni shoutaishimashita" to "Watashi wa Mira-san ni pa-ti- ni shoutaisaremashita". Is the phrase after conversion with passive verb correct? With the two "ni" which seems bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is correct, but to avoid the double "ni" you could say "Watashi wa Mira-san no pa-ti- ni shoutaisaremashita" - I guess she's inviting you to her own party.

There is no problem with having "ni" twice - they do very different jobs (one is "by" and the other is "to") but just happen to be the same kana.

Comment: In this case, you could write: 私はミラさんからパーティに招待されました.

から would indicate where the passive action was originating from.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question actually. Transforming "chichi wa mai asa hayaku watashi o okoshimasu" to passive verb, is " watashi wa chichi ni mai asa hayaku okoshisaremasu" correct? I am not sure about the placement of " mai asa hayaku".

Comment: One of the great things about Japanese is that you can change the word order. You won't change the meaning, but you can change the emphasis. "Chichi ni mai asa hayaku okoshisaremasu" emphasises that it is my father that wakes me (rather than anyone else) whereas "Mai asa hayaku chichi ni okoshisaremasu" emphasises the fact that I am woken up early every morning. Note that it is not necessary to say "watashi wa" unless you want to emphsise that it is you being woken up rather than someone else.

Comment: ^「おこしされます」じゃなくて「おこされます」です。 × okoshisaremasu → ○ okosaremasu